# Do a global search on records by GUID

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011 I have some code that is looking to some accounts to do some processing, but it is coming back with an error and only referencing the record that has the problem by its GUID. I've tried looking into the accounts and none of them have the GUID that it is returning. Is there a way that I can do a global search in CRM (or its SQL database) to find a record by its GUID?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Every entity is stored in a separate table. There's no entity/table that stores GUIDs and table names (= `EntityReference`) from every table. As with SQL, to find all GUIDs for all tables, you have to search each entity/table separately.

Alternatively, you can make an entity that stores this kind of information and create a `Create` plugin for every accessible entity in the system, but this kind of overhead is likely unwanted and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

On [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/), Demian Rasko created a project that allows you to search all entities based on a guid, which then shows a result of the tables where the guid was (or was not) found. See [Guid Finder Solution for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://crm2011guidfinder.codeplex.com/).

I have not (yet) tried it myself, but it looks promising. It is a plugin for CRM.